# How to specify replyUrlsWithType programmatically

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to set the `replyUrlsWithType` programmatically on an app [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest) within Azure AD. However, the REST API  for updating the [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity) only seems to support setting the replyUrls property, which does not enable the type property to be set. Is there a supported way to set the `replyUrlsWithType` programmatically?

The team I'm working with has used Fiddler to take a look at how the Azure portal sets the type property and have hacked the following to get it to work, but we are looking for a supported method if there is one:

```
$UpdateAppResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/$appId?api-version=2.0" `
    -Method "PATCH" `
    -Headers @{"Authorization"="$($Response.token_type) $($Response.access_token)"; "Accept"="*/*"; } `
    -ContentType "application/json" `
    -Body "{`"id`":`"$appId`",`"replyUrlsWithType`":[{`"url`":`"https://$HostName`",`"type`":`"Web`"},{`"url`":`"msauth://$ReversedHostName`",`"type`":`"InstalledClient`"}, {`"url`":`"msauth.$ReversedHostName://auth`",`"type`":`"InstalledClient`"}]}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the past, the application registered in Azure portal could only be one type. So, the Azure AD Graph API was able to set `replyUrls`.

However, new application registered in Azure portal could support both type at the same time. Based on the fiddler traces, the Azure AD Graph seems to updated to support that.

The url `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/$appId?api-version=2.0` is a typical url of AAD Graph API. Maybe just the document has not been updated.

---

However, we suggest you use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).  It is an unified center for managing lots of Microsoft Cloud Resources.

You can [Get application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [Update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) with Microsoft Graph API.

For example, you can make a `PATCH` request with the following body:

```
{
    "publicClient": {
        "redirectUris": [
            "myapp://auth"
        ]
    },
    "web": {
        "redirectUris": [
            "https://devchat.com/",
            "http://localhost/",
            "https://mytest.com/"
        ],
        "implicitGrantSettings": {
            "enableAccessTokenIssuance": false,
            "enableIdTokenIssuance": false
        }
    }
}
```

Then all the platforms will be added:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jack Jia.  This looks like a great solution.

Comment: Hi Jack, I'm trying to programmatically create an App Registration with SPA support. This, as far as I can tell, cannot be done using the current (v1) Graph API. I've tried calling https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/$appId?api-version=2.0 but I'm getting a Bad Request with Request_InvalidDataContractVersion code. The same call when done from Azure Portal (edit Manifest page) succeeds. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is looking to configure similarly as a SPA, you can set the property to `"spa"` instead of `"web"`. This was a headache for me so hopefully helpful for others:

Instead of:

```
"web": {
    "redirectUris": [
```

use

```
"spa": {
    "redirectUris": [
```

A one liner for the Azure Cloud Shell (bash):

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<APP REG OBJECT GUID (object ID not the App ID)>' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{"spa":{"redirectUris":["https:<APP DOMAIN (and port if needed)>"]}}'
```

Comment: Can I append the url without having to overwrite the entire array?