# Is there a PowerShell equivalent to "az rest"?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I recently discovered the `az rest` command, which allows me to perform authenticated REST commands, without having to worry about acquiring tokens.

https://www.codeisahighway.com/native-azure-rest-api-calls-now-available-in-azure-cli-2-0-67/

```
az rest --method patch --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/johndoe@azuresdkteam.onmicrosoft.com" --body "{\"displayName\": \"jondoe2\"}"
```

Is there an equivalent in Azure Powershell? I need to do a call which is not available via any of the `AzAd...` cmdlets. I would imagine something like `Invoke-AzRestMethod`, but this does not exist.

Edit: I want to execute calls which are not available via the Azure AD Cmdlets (yet). Like using the new [typed replyUrls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685870/how-to-specify-replyurlswithtype-programmatically) directly, or uploading custom policies for AAD B2C (Beta API).

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest?

Comment: az rest automatically acquires the required token as far as I can see. I thought Invoke-WebRequest did not do this.

Comment: You're correct. Invoke-WebRequest will not acquire the token. I could not find any Cmdlet equivalent of `az rest`. You mentioned that you need to do something with Azure AD. Just wondering if you have seen Azure AD Cmdlets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0?

Comment: Thank you. I should have put more details into the question. I want to execute code which is not available via the Azure AD Cmdlets (yet). Like using the new typed replyUrls (v2.0 API), or uploading custom policies for AAD B2C (Beta API).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now do this with the Az Powershell module

```
Invoke-AzRestMethod
      -Path <String>
      -Method <String>
      [-Payload <String>]
      [-AsJob]
      [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/manage-azure-resources-invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-5.9.0

Comment: Released two weeks after I asked the original question... fascinating

Comment: This command cannot be used for Azure AD calls.  Description says construct and perform HTTP request to Azure resource management endpoint only.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in powershell command equals `az rest` currently.

My workaround is to use the command below, you could simply use it to get the specific token for a specific resource with your login account/service principal, e.g. `https://management.azure.com`, `https://graph.microsoft.com`, it can also be other resources, even the `app-id` of your custom API in AAD.

**Sample**:

```
Connect-AzAccount
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$Token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $resource).AccessToken
```

[image]

Decode the token, we can find the `audience` is correct.

[image]

After getting the token, you can simply use the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7) to call any REST API you want, for the format, you can check this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60255738/9455659).